# R: Silhouette function results in table

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

Is there a way to receive the results of the silhouette function in R in a table showing 1) the number of the clusters and 2) the average silhouette width for each cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything that you need is returned by the silhouette function. Just capture that and summarize it any way that you want. Here is an example using the built-in iris data.

```
library(cluster)
Iris_KM3 = kmeans(iris[,1:4],3)
SIL = silhouette(Iris_KM3$cluster, dist(iris[,1:4]))

aggregate(SIL[,3], list(SIL[,1]), mean)
  Group.1          x
1       1 0.07624005
2       2 0.49471909
3       3 0.62148628
```

If you run the above code, try typing just `SIL` or `str(SIL)` to see what the function is giving you.

Comment: That's what I was searching for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `summary()` function to see all details of the `silhouette()` function for clustering analysis. I will follow @G5W's answer. You can get the number of observations in each cluster as well.

```
library(cluster)
Iris_KM3 <- kmeans(iris[,1:4],3)
SIL <- silhouette(Iris_KM3$cluster, dist(iris[,1:4]))
summary_SIL <- summary(SIL)
cluster_SIL <- t(rbind(summary_SIL[["clus.sizes"]], summary_SIL[["clus.avg.widths"]]))
colnames(cluster_SIL) <- c("No. of Obs", "Avg. Silh. Width")
```